# Microsoft Word insertion point marker changed shape

Tags: microsoft-word

I'll preface this by noting that while I am not sure this is the correct stackexchange site for this question, it's the best I could find. Feel free to move it if it needs moving.

While using Microsoft Word (not sure of the version, either 2016 or Office 365), I accidentally hit some keys on my keyboard. I don't know which specific keys, but whatever I did changed the shape of the insertion point marker to have what looks like a little "flag" on the top of it, as seen below:

[image: The text "r:" followed by an insertion point marker with a small left-pointing triangle on top of it]

Looking around online suggests that it might have something to do with language settings, but going into options->language, nothing seems out of the ordinary; it's just set to English, the system default.

When in math mode, editing equations, the cursor is normal (which is especially odd as it was in math mode when the problem started...), and it does persist when starting new documents, so it's not a document setting unless it changed a default.

Answer (score 0):

Well, while I still have no idea what caused it, closing and reopening Word fixed it.

I am still curious just what this changed cursor means, but it's no longer a problem that needs fixing.